# Flutter pemissions_handler bug

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I have an issue with flutter permissions_handler and asking permissions for bluetooth always returns permission denied. This link: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/884 says that including the bluetooth permission twice in the manifest.xml file solves the problem but when uploading a version to the play store rejects it because of permission duplicated error

this are the permission I include in the manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Does anyone know how to solve the issue and to solve the problems with the PlayStore?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this same problem this answer worked for me

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    tools:node="replace" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

changing this lines for the bluetooth permissions